# Using XPath for expression in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

When evaluating an XPath for expression in Java, example:

```
        String expr = "for $x in * return $x";

        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) m_xpath.evaluate(
                expr, 
                docXML, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

I get an error:

```
        javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Extra illegal tokens: '$', 'x', 'in', ...
```

I realize I could simply use `*` as the value of `expr`, but I am trying to understand how to use the XPath for expressions in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite other answers and comments, `for $x in * return $x` *is* XPath.
  However, `for` requires XPath **2.0** (or greater), but **the default implementation of the `javax.xml.xpath` API only supports XPath 1.0.**

Consider using [Saxonica's](https://www.saxonica.com/) implementations for excellent XPath 2.0+ support in Java (and .NET).

Comment: One slight caveat: `javax.xml.xpath` is an API, not an implementation. The default implementation of this API in the JDK only supports XPath 1.0; other implementations of the same API (such as Saxon) support later versions.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Answer adjusted.  Thank you!